# twig symfony directory separator

Tags: symfony, directory, twig, separator

I use twig in a personal project and would like to access to files as symfony sensiolab with ":" as directory separator. For example :

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
{% extends ':default:base.html.twig' %}
```

Just need to replace ":" by "/" without bundle..

Does someone know how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

The colons in the template inheritance structure are not to reference directories but resources, the normal format is:

```
{% extends 'bundle_name:controller:template'%}
```

The different combinations of the parts will tell Symfony where to find the resource, for example:

`{% extends "::base.html.twig" %}` means that the `base.html.twig` template is in the global app resources folder.

```
{% extends "AcmeDemoBundle::part.html.twig" %}
```

This means that the template is located inside the Resources folder of the `AcmeDemo Bundle`.